# Symmetrical Time Dilation

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation

I have lately been researching time dilation and relativity, and thought about this phenomenon:

Take two people, Observer A, and Observer B, who are both carrying clocks. Observer A travels through space at 50% of the speed of light, while Observer B is stationary. According to Einstein, Observer B would see Observer A's clock ticking slower, because it is moving at a high speed relative to Observer B's clock. And Observer A would see Observer B's clock moving faster. Everything made sense until I realized that Observer A would also see Observer B moving 50% of the speed of light away from him since speed is relative. In fact, Observer A could say that they are moving away from each other, both traveling at 25% the speed of light. This would lead to symmetrical time dilation. I got very confused at these scenarios, and wondered if time dilation is even real, since both observers could say absolute different things. If they were both carrying clocks, would observer A's clock have ticked slower, or Observer B's.

Comment: I assume that posting twice was an accident. Why have you not deleted one of them to fix the error?